# How to truncate magento table using collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom table. 
I want to truncate the table using Magento collection without SQL query.

Hope someone will provide some useful information

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late but :

```
  $tableName = $collection->getResource()->getMainTable();
  $conn = $collection->getConnection();
  $conn->truncateTable($tableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example for cron/schedule table:

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');

Mage::app("default");

/** @var Mage_Cron_Model_Resource_Schedule $cron */
$cron = Mage::getResourceModel('cron/schedule');

$cron->getReadConnection()->delete(
    $cron->getMainTable(),
    '1=1'
);
```

If you extend Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract in your module this example will work and you should use getWriteConnection instead of getReadConnection.

Comment: It will delete all records. As i know there is no way to run truncate command without sql query.